# How to add tabs is Qtabwidget in a new process?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, python-multiprocessing, qtabwidget

I want to add a tab in a new process on button click event and terminate it after sometime.
On Button click a new process is created but tabs are not created.
Please help me regrading this issue!!!
Here is what is tried:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import multiprocessing
class createProc(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self,mnWndObj):
        super(createProc,self).__init__()
        self.Obj = mnWndObj

    def run(self):
        print "Process is being created!!!"
        tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.Obj.tabwnd.addTab(tab,"tab")

class MainWnd(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWnd,self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabwnd = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.webwnd = Qt.QWebView()
        self.webwnd.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.google.co.in/"))
        self.webwnd.show()
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Create Process")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabwnd)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.webwnd)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.crProc)

    def crProc(self):
        p = createProc(self)
        p.start()
        print "Process Name",p.name     

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWnd()
    m.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please copy your code to the question, instead of linking to an image of the code. Also, you should provide more detail of what is going on.

Comment: It gives Runtime Error:
Process Name createProc-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1215, in load_build
    setstate = getattr(inst, "__setstate__", None)
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type QTabWidget was never called

Comment: @raman.pndy. As it stands, your code will never work in PyQt. You cannot use multiprocessing to embed a separate process like that. Maybe you should explain what problem you are trying to solve by trying to do this.

Comment: In Pyqt ,qwebview has a drawback in terms of memory as when multiple pages are loaded in qwebview memory leak happens . so to minimize this i want to open each url in webview in qtabwidget in each tab with a new process so that after some time i can terminate those process to free the memory. So anyone please suggest me the right approach to do this.

Comment: @raman.pndy. The webkit classes are effectively obsolete. Switch to PyQt5 and use [Qt WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html). If you can't switch, there's nothing that can be done about the webkit memory leaks. It's a well-known problem, and it will never be fixed. (NB: official support for Qt4 ends in December this year, and 4.8.7 will almost certainly be the last release).

Comment: @ekhumoro. Yeah Sure i can't switch to PyQt5. But what if i unreference the webview object and delete the instance, will it work? or please tell me some other way to minimize the memory usage of webview instance so that i will get rid of application crashing?

Comment: @raman.pndy. AFAIK, python doesn't generally release memory back to the system, so deleting objects in-process usually won't help much. The only certain way to reclaim the memory would be to kill the current process and start a new one. See [this qt forum thread](http://forum.qt.io/topic/10832/memory-size-increases-per-page-load) for more details.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I somehow switched to PyQt5 Version. But still my problem is not solved. Qt WebEngine is not present in pyqt5 . please tell me any example to use this to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

Comment: @raman.pndy. Are you on Windows? If not, WebEngine should be available in pyqt5 on all other platforms.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Yep i am working on windows. i didn't find the WebEngine in pyqt5 intead i found Qt WebEngine wrapper. but i don't know how to use it :(

Comment: @raman.pndy. That wrapper is only for QML applications, so I don't think it's going to be any use to you.

Comment: @ekhumoro. Please Tell me the way to implement Qt Web Engine in pyqt5 .

Comment: @raman.pndy. It's not normally possible on Windows, due to a [compiler incompatibility](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html#module-PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets). So I think you're stuck with webkit. Perhaps you should ask a **new** question on SO, and make it *specifically* about how to work around the memory leak problems in qt webkit. I don't currently have any answers for that myself - I'm just assuming it isn't possible (but I could be wrong).